# Graphical representation for triangular inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Is it possible to represent all the problems graphically that involve triangular inequality to solve them. For example, to prove that for any series $a_n \to a$ for every $m\gt n$ hence there is only one limit say $a$ and I can assume it graphically but the proof that $\lim(a_n+b_n) \to (a+b)$ as it approaches $n$ also employs triangular inequality but I don't see it graphically.

Can someone present some graphical representation to this theorem?

Comment: Do you mean $a_n \ge n$ ?

Comment: I have update question..hope its more clear now.

Comment: is there any idea someone has on it ?